# Pagination on custom post type without plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

What's the best way to display pagination on a custom post type archive page without a plugin? I tried `paginate_links()` didn't work.

I'm using a custom query and here's the code:

```
$args = [
    'post_type'   => 'on_my_mind',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
];
$omm  = new WP_Query($args); ?>

<?php if ($omm->have_posts()): while ($omm->have_posts()): $omm->the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'on_my_mind') ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: what happened? no links? wrong pages? 404 error?

Comment: No links. Nothing happened! Nothing showed, thus nothing to click at all. What do I do?

Comment: are you using a custom query in your custom post type archive page? possibly just post the full code of the template.

Comment: Yes I'm using a custom query and here's the code:
$args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  'on_my_mind',
    'post_status'     =>  'publish'
);
$omm = new WP_Query($args);
?>

Comment: <?php if ($omm -> have_posts()): while ($omm -> have_posts()): $omm -> the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'on_my_mind' ) ?>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="cell small-12">
                        <?php $omm -> the_posts_pagination(); ?>
                        <?php $omm->paginate_links(); ?>
                    </div>